# CSS3Renderer ignores projectonMatrix property?

Tags: three.js

I'm doing augmented reality with Three.js and recenlty I tried to combine WebGL and CSS3 rendering to render both 3D content and DOM objects (Mostly for video playback) at the same time. I've started with [Closing the gap between html and webgl](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/04/30/closing-the-gap-between-html-and-webgl/) tutorial, but I cannot get correct visualization using CSS (Although WebGL working fine).

Basically, when doing AR, we have two matrices we have to apply to our scene: **projection matrix** and **camera matrix**. The projection matrix (row-major) usually looks like this:

```
var projectionMatrix = [ 1.820090055466, 0, -0.000550820783, 0,  
                         0, 3.227676868439, -0.036605358124, 0,  
                         0, 0, -1.000199913979,-0.200020000339,  
                         0, 0, -1, 0 
];
```

And camera matrix (row-major) represents a rigid 3D transform (R|t composition) that represents camera transformation in virtual world:

```
var cameraMatrix = [ 0.790828585625,0.296402275562,-0.535477280617,-0.309822082520,  
                    -0.612037420273,0.382129371166,-0.692378044128,-0.447699964046,  
                    -0.000600785017,0.875284433365,0.483608126640,-0.637073278427,  
                     0.000000000000,0.000000000000,0.000000000000,1.000000000000];
```

With WebGL it's pretty easy to apply these matrices to a pipeline:

```
self.wglCamera.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
self.wglCamera.projectionMatrix.set(
    pm[0], pm[1],   pm[2],  pm[3],
    pm[4], pm[5],   pm[6],  pm[7],
    pm[8], pm[9],   pm[10], pm[11],
    pm[12], pm[13], pm[14], pm[15]);


self.wglCamera.matrix.set(
    cm[0],  cm[1],  cm[2],  cm[3],
    cm[4],  cm[5],  cm[6],  cm[7],
    cm[8],  cm[9],  cm[10], cm[11],
    cm[12], cm[13], cm[14], cm[15]);
```

When I do the same for CSS3 camera, I get incorrect rendering result ([VIDEO](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hy54eiflhc6oroz/WebGL_CSS.mov?dl=0.)):

[image: Wrong CSS3Renderer results]

There are two issues:

- Red texture (CSS3Object) non-uniformly scaled (it's square in fact)
- It always sits in screen center, however it should be located where a blue grid is.

After analyzing CSS3Renderer implementation, I found that only camera FOV property is used to set perspective effect, but the **projectionMatrix property is totally ignored when rendering with CSS3Renderer**. Is it intended?

```
// https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js#L225
this.render = function ( scene, camera ) {

    var fov = 0.5 / Math.tan( THREE.Math.degToRad( camera.fov * 0.5 ) ) * _height;

    ...

    camera.matrixWorldInverse.getInverse( camera.matrixWorld );

    // Why we don't use camera.projection Matrix here?
    var style = "translate3d(0,0," + fov + "px)" + getCameraCSSMatrix( camera.matrixWorldInverse ) +
        " translate3d(" + _widthHalf + "px," + _heightHalf + "px, 0)";

    ...

};
```

And, if yes, how I can achieve desired result?

I've tried to pass PM * CM to camera matrix, but both problems still exists. Mainly I more worried about ignored translation, since rotation looks good.

I'd appreciate any ideas/suggestions! Thanks.

Comment: Uh oh! Yes, it does ignore the projectionMatrix. We should look into this...